# Constrain reducer by more than action type

Tags: javascript, redux

I have checkbox filters on multiple pages and want to keep them independent in different parts of the store. Creating very specific action types such as `TOGGLE_CHECKBOX_SEARCHPAGE_BODYTYPE` feels wrong, as it would need specific reducer for every page and every filter type or a lot of checking inside one big reducer.
So I think action should look like this:

```
{
  type: 'TOGGLE_CHECKBOX',
  page: 'search',
  filterName: 'bodyType',
  payload: 'xxxl'
}
```

I can then write function returning constrained reducer:

```
function constrain(constraints, reducer) {
  return function(state, action) {
    const allConstraintsPass = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(constraints)
      .every( propName => action[propName] === constraints[propName])

    if ( ! allConstraintsPass ) {
      return reducer(state, {}) // possibly never matching {type: NaN}
    }

    return reducer(state, action)
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
function someReducer(state, action) {
  state = state || {}
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE_CHECKBOX':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {[action.payload]: !state[action.payload]})
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const fuelOnSearchPage = constrain({filterName: 'bodyType', page: 'search'}, someReducer)

console.log(fuelOnSearchPage(undefined, {filterName: 'fuelType', page: 'search', type: 'TOGGLE_CHECKBOX', payload: 'xxl'}));
console.log(fuelOnSearchPage(undefined, {filterName: 'bodyType', page: 'search', type: 'TOGGLE_CHECKBOX', payload: 'xs'}));
console.log(fuelOnSearchPage(undefined, {filterName: 'bodyType', page: 'search', type: 'TOGGLE_CHECKBOX', payload: 'xxl'}));
console.log(fuelOnSearchPage(undefined, {filterName: 'fuelType', page: 'search', type: 'OTHER_ACTION', payload: 'xxl'}));
console.log(fuelOnSearchPage(undefined, {type: 'OTHER_ACTION'}));
```

I'm not sure if this is idiomatic redux, though. In this case filterName and page seem to have similar use as type, in some cases it may be unclear what should be the type. 
Do you have more clear solution for this type of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not wrong to create very specific action types because actions are very specific. You're doing exactly the same thing in your example, it just looks a bit more complicated and is harder to test (and it's not following the [FSA](https://github.com/acdlite/flux-standard-action) standard which is highly recommended). I usually namespace my action types like so:

```
export const SEARCH = {
    BODYTYPE: {
        TOGGLE: 'SEARCH.BODYTYPE.TOGGLE'
    }
}
```

Then used as: `SEARCH.BODYTYPE.TOGGLE` or perhaps `types.SEARCH.BODYTYPE.TOGGLE` depending on how you import it.

Instead of that constrain function you could create reducers based on a prefix, something like:

```
createCheckboxReducer(prefix) {
    return function(state, action) {
        switch(action.type) {
            case `${prefix}.TOGGLE`:
                //do something
                return state;
        }
    }
}

// somewhere else
createCheckboxReducer('SEARCH.BODYTYPE')
```

Pretty much the same thing but this is definitely kosher in my book. A side note: If my action types are nested deeper than this example that's usually a sign that it's time to refactor and break things up into smaller modules.

*Note: this is all untested code*

Comment: Yep, adding additional targeting information to actions and reducers is very common, whether it be by adding prefixes to action types, or adding additional data to the payload of an action.  My Redux addons catalog has numerous utilities and libraries listed that can generate actions and reducers for reuse: https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links